# getchar having trouble reading due to scanf fail

Tags: c, stdio

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float f;
    char s;
    if (scanf("%f", &f) == 1) {
        printf("%f", f);
    }
    else {
        s = getchar();
        printf("'%c'", s);
    }
}
```

This works for floats, and when I enter '*' or '/'.
Why does this not work for '+' and '-'?

```
 ./a.out 
*
'*'
```

This is the output, and this is what I want. But in case of '+'

```
./a.out
+
'
'
```

This is happening and I want '+' to be the output.

Seems like scanf's failure somehow interferes with the getchar()

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: *"Why does this not work"* - why does *what* not "work" ?? You need to define what your actual input is, your expected output (and why you expect it), your actual output, and anything you've done thus far to decipher why the latter two are different (if anything). [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66559846/edit) with that additional information please.

Comment: Hopefully the edit is better formed? @WhozCraig

Comment: You'll end up in knots mixing input methods. Use `fgets()` for input, extract its data with `sscanf()` and if it's bad input, discard the string and obtain another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is a valid char to start a float value, so `scanf` will consume it before failing because there is no number coming after `+`.

Then `getchar` will read the next char after `+` which is the `\n` newline.

If you want to catch the leading `+` (or `-`) in inputs that are not valid float values, such as `"+\n"` or `"-xyz"`, then you'll have to read it as string then parse it after that, for example with `sscanf`, and use it as a string if it doesn't parse as a float.

Comment: That's very helpful, is there an alternate way to do what I want?

Comment: @ESarda See the last paragraph I added at the end.